# How to add textboxes dynamically on a asp.net webform using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to add textboxes dynamically to a web form on the click of a button. The number will be provided in a textbox. For better understanding an image is given below:
[Dynamic TextBoxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYDi6.png)

Comment: you want to create textbox or label?

Comment: I want to create textboxes in the exact form shown in the image

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `append()` method to add new elements dynamically to DOM. I have created a demo for better understanding here : https://jsfiddle.net/p2hr1a1f/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="noTxt">
<button class="btnCreate">
Create
</button>

<div class="txtBox-container">

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnCreate').on('click', function(){
    var txtBox="<input type='text' class='newtxtBox'><br>";
    l=$('.noTxt').val();
    console.log(l);
    for(var i=1;i<=l;i++){
        $('.txtBox-container').append(txtBox);
      console.log(txtBox);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: this is not the thing I want...the textboxes will be added one after anoher horizontally for a fixed width and the row is full it will move to the next row.