# Automate control creation C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am making a form for user input where each time the user clicks a button a new textbox is added for them to input into.

I am able to create the textboxes no problem but I am having trouble naming them.  They all need to have different names(otherwise they will overwrite one another) so I want to do something like:

```
string strName = "txt"+counter.toString(); 
HtmlGenericControl gc = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

InputList.Controls.Add(gc);

TextBox strName = new TextBox();

strName.Text = "hello world"+counter.toString();
gc.addControls.Add(strName);
```

Vs doesn't like this but I need to be able to provide many autogenerated textboxes.  Any advice on how to get around this issue or can you recommend another way?

Comment: You should use an array or List.

Comment: What do you mean by "problem but I am having trouble naming them. They all need to have different names(otherwise they will overwrite one another)"? Can you show an example of this?

Comment: What's the reason behind having 2 variables with the same name `strName `?

Comment: jarnold, I took a guess at the platform you are using but do mention and tag it yourself... I don't think you would be helped by a WPF answer. The lack of details is probably why you are at -2 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need `string strName = "txt"+counter.toString();` for?

Instead of changing the `Text` property of the `TextBox`es, you can try changing the `ID` property like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl gc = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
gc.ID = "li"+counter.toString(); //This is needed to take it later
InputList.Controls.Add(gc);
TextBox strName = new TextBox();
strName.Text = "txtbox"+counter.toString();
gc.addControls.Add(strName);
```

Then, if you want to get the values from these `TextBox`es you should use:

```
TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)(InputList.FindControl("li1").FindControl("txtbox1"));  
var inputText = txtbox.Text; //This contains the text inside the `TextBox`
```

EDIT

As Vilx- mentioned, each time you will click the add button a new postback will occur so, you have to figure out a way to load the already created `TextBox`es on postback.
The best way is to dynamically create the `input` fields using JavaScript/JQuery completely in front-end and send them back to server on form submission.

Here is an example: [How to add textboxes dynamically on a asp.net webform using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963615/how-to-add-textboxes-dynamically-on-a-asp-net-webform-using-javascript):

Comment: Great point with the postback and having to recreate all the previous textboxes.  Thanks, I'll switch things up and put this functionality in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WebForms is a PITA when it comes to dynamically generated controls. I would suggest finding a good editable GridView-like control and using that. Let someone else deal with the mess.

Othwerwise remember that you need to give them different IDs and in every `Page_Init` recreate them EXACTLY where you left them. The same IDs, the same place in the control tree. And when you're done with that, you'll notice that the performance of the "add" button is crappy because it does a postback every time you press it. Ideally you should add the additional textboxes on client side (aka Javascript) without touching the server at all. And if you do that then you either need to abandon the entire control paradigm at all and instead work directly with `Request.Form` (at least for these few textboxes), or you need to somehow figure out in your `Page_Init` how many textboxes where to add so that they match what the client side created.

So... good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for the tips. Could you provide an example of a a good editable GridView?

Comment: @jarnold - I'm afraid I don't know very many, you'll have to search for one yourself. I know that Devexpress and Telerik both sell something half decent, but they're not cheap, and at least the Devexpress one (I haven't used Telerik) had a rather lackluster performance.

Answer (score -1):

Variable names are only available at compile time. You cannot create variable names at run time. Instead, you should use an array or a List.

Comment: Controls do have a .Name property